# Android place view (TreeView) on top of MainLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, treeview

So I have this MainLayout which simply consists of a Floating Action Button (FAB) right now:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using [this library](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) to create a treeView similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DZjN.png)

I create the AndroidTreeView object in the MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    val treeView = AndroidTreeView(this, root) // 'this' is the context
    // ...
    setContentView(treeView.view)
}
```

This will obviously only display the content of the treeView and not the mainLayout.

**How can I show the TreeView and the Button at the same time / render the TreeView on top of the MainLayout?**

I tried to add the FAB to the view using addView:

```
val view = treeView.view as ViewGroup
view.addView(floatingActionButton2)
```

But this results in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`

In an example project the author of TreeView used **Fragments** for this. But is this really necessary in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by inflating the MainLayout on top of the rootLayout. I tried a similar solution to this before but I probably used "R.id.content" instead of "android.R.id.content".

This code belongs to the bottom of the onCreate method of the MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // ...
    setContentView(treeView.view)

    val rootLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(android.R.id.content)
    View.inflate(this, R.layout.main_layout, rootLayout)
}
```